# UISearchBar's height is incorrect when presenting search result controller

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, uisearchresultscontroller

I have a search bar in **tableView's header view**, and I don't change the height of it(default is 56pt). When search bar is active and its position goes top of the screen, it's height becomes 50pt. It will both happen on iPhone or simulator, version iOS 11.

**First appear:**

```
<UISearchBar: 0x7f94b6646900; frame = (0 0; 375 56); text = ''; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60400025fc20>; layer = <CALayer: 0x604000225fe0>>
```

**Editing:**

```
<UISearchBar: 0x7f94b6646900; frame = (0 14; 375 50); text = ''; autoresize = W+TM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60400025fc20>; layer = <CALayer: 0x604000225fe0>>
```

It results in a weird gap between the search bar and result controller's view.
[image: gap]

Thanks for any ideas.

**Edit1:**
Here's my code:

```
fileprivate func configSearchBar() -> Void {
    let bar = self.searchBar
    var size = bar.frame.size

    let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
    bar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWith(color: .white, size: size),
                           for: .any,
                           barMetrics: .default)
    let colorWhenEditing = UIColor.colorFromHexString("#FAFAFA")
    if UIDevice.isIPHONEX() {
        bar.barTintColor = colorWhenEditing
    } else {
        bar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWith(color: colorWhenEditing, size: CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height + statusBarHeight)),
                               for: .topAttached,
                               barMetrics: .default)
    }
    size = CGSize(width: bar.frame.size.width - 30, height: 30)
    let image = UIImage.imageWith(color: UIColor(hexString: "#F0F0F0"), size: size)?.zoom(toSize: size, cornerRadius: 4)
    bar.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)

    bar.searchTextPositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 5, vertical: 0)
}

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar
```

**Edit2:** - Search controller and search bar initialization:

```
// Main view controller
lazy var searchResultController: UISearchController = {
    let vc = MailSearchResultViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    let sc = UISearchController(searchResultsController: vc)
    sc.searchResultsUpdater = self
    sc.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
    sc.delegate = self
    return sc
}()
var searchBar: UISearchBar {
    return searchResultController.searchBar
}
// MailSearchResultViewController - viewDidLoad:
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Comment: Share your `UISearchBar` code.

Comment: How did you add it as a header view to the table view? have you done it in the code?

Comment: @ImadAli Add code in Edit1.

Comment: @AhmadF See Edit1

Comment: Would you try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987619/how-to-open-uisearchbar-like-iphone-settings-search-bar/47988164#47988164) instead of doing it programmatically?

Comment: @KleinMioke where you're configuring the `self.searchBar` code or storyboard? Share the same.

Comment: @ImadAli check the newest edit, thanks a lot

Comment: @KleinMioke your `navigationBar` is Translucent  or Opaque..?

Comment: @Gokul translucent

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43278771/5329717 Perhaps it will solve your problem.

Comment: Hey just a guess ,try unchecking the adjust Scroll view inset from the storyboard by selecting the view controller in layout options. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554898/uiscrollview-not-scrolling-after-unchecking-adjust-scroll-view-insets-xcode-6

Comment: @PallaviSrikhakollu I don't use storyboard, but I set that property programmatically to false. That's not work.

Comment: Did you find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is with automatically adjust scrollView Insets. To resolve this problem do the Following

1. Go to storyboard.
2. Select controller containing searchbarcontroller
3. Go to attribute inspector
4. Uncheck Adjust Scroll View Insets

Comment: I don't use storyboard, I programmatically set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to false in search result view controller and UISearchController, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on iOS 11 and from the comments it seems you have a navigation controller, you should consider putting the search bar directly inside your navigation item instead of the table view header which will still be the method you should use on iOS 10 and before. You can check out the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/2897305-searchcontroller).

It seems that since Apple introduced this new way of displaying the search bar UIKit is no longer correctly able to display it from the table view header on iOS 11 and later. You can also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47503666/search-bar-overlapping-status-bar-in-search-controller) (in ObjC) where this same change introduces your same problem or [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/201/?time=361) from Apple.